# The whole list of the array from store isn't rendered

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, alpine.js

Why the whole list of the array from store isn't rendered, I get only the title in the div, but not getting the country, price, etc, from the store.
https://codesandbox.io/s/html-template-forked-ywqs9r?file=/index.html

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="”module”" src="./script.js"></script>
    <title>Vesna</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="content">
      <div class="content__mid" x-data="">
        <template x-for="item in $store.products.items" :key="item.id">
          <p class="content__mid-item" x-text="item.title"></p>
          <p class="content__mid-item" x-text="item.country"></p>
          <p class="content__mid-item" x-text="item.manufacturer"></p>
          <p class="content__mid-item" x-text="item.price"></p>
          <p class="content__mid-item" x-text="item.validDate"></p>
        </template>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Really weird. I get errors just by commenting out some of the p tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is the right answer, I have never used Alpine.js.

I initially noticed that the example got really wonky and started erroring out as I commented out each `<p>` tag. However, by searching for "Alpine js for loop examples", I noticed that [it was using a wrapping div](https://larainfo.com/blogs/alpine-js-for-loop-example) when it needed multiple tags in the loop.

Maybe its templating does not allow multiple children under `<template>`, sort of like React used to require a single element for a component.

```
<template x-for="item in $store.products.items" :key="item.id">
  <div>
    <p class="content__mid-item" x-text="item.title"></p>
    <p class="content__mid-item" x-text="item.country"></p>
    <p class="content__mid-item" x-text="item.manufacturer"></p>
    <p class="content__mid-item" x-text="item.price"></p>
    <p class="content__mid-item" x-text="item.validDate"></p>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image]